# Upon bootup, all iptables are lost because the kernel module ip_set is not loaded

Tags: iptables, kernel-modules, centos, ipset, iptables-persistent

i can get iptables to whitelist / blacklist using ipset members, but after a reboot, the iptables are emptied out because the kernel module is not loaded.  Have limped along in the past by customizing the iptables init script, but there has to be an out-of-the-box method.

On CentOS/RHEL 6.5, you can install ipset from the base repository.  The first line from

```
yum info
```

says

> IP sets are a framework inside the Linux 2.4.x and 2.6.x kernel, which can be
>               : administered by the ipset utility.

so i was surprised there is a problem with a kernel module:

```
ip6tables: Loading additional modules: nf_conntrack_netbios_ns ... OK
iptables: Applying firewall rules: iptables-restore v1.4.7: Kernel module ip_set 
is not loaded in.
```

i have tried both ip-set and ip_set for this module name with no luck:

```
/etc/sysconfig/iptables-config:
   IPTABLES_MODULES="nf_conntrack_netbios_ns ip_set"
```

There may also be separate modules for each ipset data structure.  In other words, a module just for ipset hash versus ipset bitmap versus ipset list.

[modinfo ip_set and other details](https://gist.github.com/rjt/ea79d97da5c122ddc9ee)

Comment: Did you try `modprobe ip_set`?

Comment: @Gnouc, yes but where would you put that at startup?  i can get iptables to block based on members of an ipset but not after reboot.  i am trying to get away from /etc/init.d/rc.local and other hacks.

Comment: What did you mean other hacks? On `Centos/Fedora`, you can use `/etc/modules-load.d`. On `Debian/Ubuntu`, use `/etc/modules`. See: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/kernel_modules#Loading

Comment: There is not a /etc/modules-load.d file or directory on my system.  Other hacks such as modifying /etc/init.d/iptables to call a script which sets up ipsets and loads the modules THEN loads iptables.

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: i did find /etc/modprobe.d/ and will try that.  However,  the kernel attempts to load ip_set based on /etc/sysconfig/iptables-config directive but fails.  Not sure modprobe.d would be any different.

Comment: Beginning of second paragraph CentOS/RHEL 6.5.

Comment: In the modinfo link to gist.github.com, i added the results of various failed attempts with /etc/modprobe.d/ipset.conf.

Comment: ipset is not kernel module, so do not try to load it as kernel or iptables module.

Comment: Then how do you explain /lib/modules/`uname -r`/kernel/net/netfilter/ipset/*.ko and modinfo ip_set.

Comment: @EeroVolotinen So you're saying the error messsage `iptables-restore v1.4.7: Kernel module ip_set 
is not loaded in.` is saying it's **not** a kernel module ?